# Prove that $F_{n} \subset U$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis

The question reads:

Let $U$ be an open subset in the compact metric space $X$.  If $\{ F_{k} : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a collection of closed subsets of $X$ such that $F_{k+1} \subset F_{k}$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} F_{k} \subset U$, then show that $F_{n} \subset U$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I think I have a proof for this but it seems way too easy considering how much information I am given.  I should add that my definition of compact means that every open covering has a finite subcovering.

$\cap_{k=1}^{\infty} F_{k} \subset U \Rightarrow \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \ x_{0} \in U$ such that $x_{0} \in F_{k} $

Let $F_{n} = \{x_{0}\}$, $n  \in \mathbb{N}$

$F_{n} \subset U\ \ \ $  Q.E.D.

Comment: You can’t *let* $F_n$ equal something of your choice: you’re *given* the sets $F_n$.

Comment: It would certainly make proving stuff easier. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: What if I define $n$ so that $F_{n} \subset U$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott -- Also, the way the question is asked suggests to me that I am given the sets $F_{k}$.  $F_{n}$ is only a specific set out of the sets $F_{k}$, so can't I define it?

Comment: @Claycrusher: Because it’s one of the sets that you’re given. Each of the sets $F_0,F_1,F_2,\ldots$ is given to you: it’s true that all that you know about them is that they’re closed, and that each one is a superset of the next, but they are specific sets, not sets that you can define to suit your fancy.

Comment: Ok.  I thought it seemed too easy.  Thanks.

Comment: @Claycrusher: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Thomas: That reminds me of what Anatole Beck once said in response to ‘wouldn’t it be nice if `some false statement` were true?’: ‘No, because then mathematics would be inconsistent!’

Comment: Didn't say it was a good thing, it would just make proving things easier. :) @BrianM.Scott